# unable to get xpath where parent and child node have different default namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am here stuck with a situation wherein I have to resolve and transform the given XML using the xslt. I need to write the xpaths to do this.

Sample xml is given below. where in both ServiceProviderGroupPackage and SecondNode have Different namespaces. I need to get the namespace of **IReference** Node to get its value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ServiceProviderGroupPackage Version="1.2.0" xmlns="http://webconnectivity.co.uk/ServiceProviderGroupPackage"
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                             xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <FirstNode Version="1.2.0" xmlns="http://www.MySite.org/Standards/MySiteMsgSvc/1"
                    xmlns:rlc="http://www.MySite.org/standards/SecondNode/1"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  </FirstNode>
  <SecondNode Version="2010-2" xmlns:ac="http://www.MySite.org/Standards/MySiteMsgSvc/1"
                      xmlns="http://www.MySite.org/standards/SecondNode/1"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xmlns:lloyds="http://www.lloyds.com/The-Market/Operating-at-Lloyds/Resources/Risk_codes">
    <Movement Sender="Sender" Receiver="Receiver">
      <Contract>
        <Type>direct</Type>
        <Nature>lm_proportional_or_nonproportional</Nature>
        <Reference>B0509311011UMR</Reference>
        <IReference>P00000062MM/13A</IReference>
      </Contract>
    </Movement>
  </SecondNode>
</ServiceProviderGroupPackage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element inherits the namespace of the parent element if not overwritten, so the IReference element has the same namespace like the SecondNode element, `http://www.MySite.org/standards/SecondNode/1`.

---

To retrieve the namespace of an arbitrary element, use the `namespace-uri(...)` function.

With XPath 2.0, you can use the wildcard-operator `*` instead of a namespace prefix:

```
namespace-uri(//*:IReference)
```

or also

```
//*:IReference/namespace-uri()
```

With XPath 1.0, you will have to check for the name in a predicate:

```
namespace-uri(//*[local-name() = "IReference"])
```

Comment: Tried using the xpath as directed by you in my xslt. no Luck with that. It does not read the combination of /*

Comment: As you say that each element inherits the namespace of parent if not overwritten the I should have no prefixes in my entire xpath. but somehow is not working that ways

Comment: Got that...Thanks for the guiding. you need to add the namespaces to the xslt with the prefixes and then add them to the xpath with whatever namespace the node falls under.